# can we use FutureBuilder with Void type

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-layoutbuilder

my question is can we use FutureBuilder with Void callbacks on using such methods whome type is

`Future<void> fun_name() async{ body }`

after creating such methods how can we pass that method to FutureBuilder widget on whatever thy type is/.

Comment: yes i believe, what is the issue you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**
you did't mention what you are trying to accomplish and why you wnna do it but here is demonstration.

**Here is demo widget**

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Future<void> fun(){
  var s=   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    return s;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: fun(),
        builder: (snap,context){
          return snap.widget; //return widget because builder's return type is widget
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

here i am doing it with `async` and `await`

```
class Test2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Future<void> delayedString() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    return;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: delayedString(),
          builder: (snap,context){
            return snap.widget; //return widget because builder's return type is widget
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```